# How to create a function for mdi container

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi

How do I create a function for my following code so that i may not have to write the following whole code to make a form be used as MDICHILD Form.

```
Students stu = null;
private void studentsToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (stu == null || stu.IsDisposed)
  {
    stu = new Students();
    stu.MdiParent = this;
    stu.Show();
  }
  else
  {
    stu.Activate();
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate as to what the problem is?

Comment: i have 10 forms in my application. i have to writed the above mentioned code for every single form to be used in mdi parant form as mdi child form i want a function that i can use with every child form for getting it be used as mdi child in my mdicontainer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
private void CreateMdiChild<T>(ref T t) where T : Form, new()
{            
    if (t == null || t.IsDisposed)
    {
        t = new T();
        t.MdiParent = this;
        t.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        if (t.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
        {
            t.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        }
        else
        {
            t.Activate();
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Students students;
private void studentsToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CreateMdiChild<Students>(ref students);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There's nothing really wrong with the code you have.  You can make it DRY with a bit of reflection:

```
    public Form CreateMdiChild(Type type, bool singleton) {
        if (singleton) {
            foreach (var child in this.MdiChildren) {
                if (child.GetType() == type) {
                    child.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
                    child.Show();
                    child.Activate();
                    return child;
                }
            }
        }
        Form form = (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        form.MdiParent = this;
        form.Show();
        return form;
    }
```

Usage:

```
 CreateMdiChild(typeof(Students), true);
```

Comment: Very nice Hans Passant. Thnaks Alot. I've tried this it is working exactly the way i wanted.

Comment: but it is not working for my else case i.e else activate. e.g if a form is already opened in mdi container it should be activated when button is pressed

Comment: I tested that scenario before posting this code.  Are you sure you are passing *true* for the singleton argument?  You can add child.Activate() to make it more explicit.

Comment: yes im passing the true for singleton. where should I add chil.Activate()?? Plzz edit it in your above mentioned code

Comment: Yes now it's right. Thanks Alot. now it's working exactly the way i was expecting. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Use Students as singleton class/form:

```
public class Students: Form
{
    private static Students _Self;
    public static Students ShowOrActivate(Form parent)
    {
        if (_Self == null)
        {
            _Self = new Students();
            _Self.MdiParent = this;
            _Self.Show();
        }
        else
            _Self.Activate();
    }
}
```

Now show the form with

```
private void studentsToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Students.ShowOrActivate(this);
}
```

Comment: Florian thanks to you as well at least your tried to help me.. but probably my demonstrations for asking the question was not good enough for you to understand